# Rails console not loading application.yml environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orientdb

I am developing a Rails application. The database used is OrientDB. I am using the `active-orient` gem for this. Everything was running fine until I updated my Bundler version. After that I am unable to open the Rails console with `rails c`. Following is the error stack

```
$ rails c
Railtie included!!
I, [2017-09-21T19:48:05.335384 #25012]  INFO -- : Orientdb4r 0.5.1, running on Ruby 2.4.0 (2016-12-24) [x86_64-linux]
WARNING: Use strings for Figaro configuration. 5432 was converted to "5432".
WARNING: Use strings for Figaro configuration. 2480 was converted to "2480".
WARNING: Use strings for Figaro configuration. 100000000 was converted to "100000000".
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): http://localhost:2480/connect/ENV['orientdb_database'] (URI::InvalidURIError)
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:73:in `parse'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/common.rb:231:in `parse'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:276:in `parse_url'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:280:in `parse_url_with_auth'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:175:in `execute'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:41:in `execute'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/resource.rb:51:in `get'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/active-orient-4f90f0276d4c/lib/rest/rest.rb:105:in `connect'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/active-orient-4f90f0276d4c/lib/rest/rest.rb:83:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/active-orient-4f90f0276d4c/lib/railtie.rb:42:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bundler/gems/active-orient-4f90f0276d4c/lib/railtie.rb:42:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/my-project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:102:in `preload'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

My `config/application.yml` file:

```
development:
    orientdb_port: 2480
    orientdb_server: <some-ip>
    orientdb_root_username: <some-username>
    orientdb_root_password: <some-password>
    orientdb_database: <some-db-name>
```

My `config/connect.yml` file that I use to provide details for OrientDB gem:

```
:orientdb:
 :server: ENV["orientdb_server"]
 :port: ENV["orientdb_port"]
 :logger: stdout
 :database: 
   :development: ENV["orientdb_database"]
   :production: ENV["orientdb_database"]
   :test:  ENV['orientdb_database']
   :staging:  ENV['orientdb_database']
 :admin:
   :user: ENV['orientdb_root_username'] 
   :pass: ENV['orientdb_root_password']
```

I think this file is not loading correctly. What could be the issue here? 
I have even downgraded the bundler version, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have something like this in your `application.yml`: `ENV['orientdb_database']` without the erb tags `<%= ... %>`? From this line in the error stack `http://localhost:2480/connect/ENV['orientdb_database']` I'm guessing you're passing a fixed string instead of the actual env variable.

Comment: Yes I have my `application.yml` as mentioned in the question and I have `config/connect.yml` has `:development: ENV["orientdb_database"]` line

Comment: If that is the case then I think that is your problem, you should have `orientdb_database: <%= ENV['orientdb_database'] %>`, because that way you're actually accessing the env variable.

Comment: I updated my question with the `config/connect.yml` file

Comment: Be careful, `:orientdb:` is not the correct syntax, it should be just `orientdb:`, the same applies for the rest. Perhaps you typed it wrong, but if not then that's definitely one of the error sources. Furthermore I insist on what I told you on a previous comment, YML files are not Ruby, if you want to evaluate a Ruby statement you have to enclose it with the erb `<%= ... %>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
development:
  orientdb_port: '2480'
  orientdb_server: 'some-ip'
  orientdb_root_username: 'some-username'
  orientdb_root_password: 'some-password'
  orientdb_database: 'some-db-name'
```

#### Note:

In the terminal run: `figaro install`
This will include you yml file in (.gitignore)

Comment: `figaro install` overwrites my existing `application.yml` file. This is a dangerous command.

Comment: you should use this command in the first place to make sure figaro works as it should work! :0)

Answer (score 0):

Your `config/connect.yml` file should look like this:

```
orientdb:
  server: <%= ENV['orientdb_server'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['orientdb_port'] %>
  logger: stdout
  database: 
    development: <%= ENV['orientdb_database'] %>
    production: <%= ENV['orientdb_database'] %>
    test:  <%= ENV['orientdb_database'] %>
    staging:  <%= ENV['orientdb_database'] %>
  admin:
    user: <%= ENV['orientdb_root_username'] %>
    pass: <%= ENV['orientdb_root_password'] %>
```

YML is *not* Ruby, so you must use the erb tags for Ruby statements to access environment variables. The same applies to `config/application.yml`.

If you look at the error message carefully you'll see that the following line pretty much gives the reason why it's failing:

```
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): http://localhost:2480/connect/ENV['orientdb_database'] (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

Specifically, `http://localhost:2480/connect/ENV['orientdb_database'] (URI::InvalidURIError)` indicates that you're passing the string `ENV['orientdb_database']` to the connection instead of the actual environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are using the latest version of active-orient (from github), look to the railties.rb-file in the lib directory.

```
connect_file = Rails.root.join('config', 'connect.yml')

databaseyml  = YAML.load_file(  connect_file )[:orientdb][:database]
```

Thus:  the yaml tags must be  :orientdb: and :database:

You can easily debug your input adding a control-output into the railtie-file
eg

```
puts "DATABASEYML :#{databaseyml.inspect}"
```

If you set the database with an Environment-variable, just assign it to ActiveOrient.database

```
ActiveOrient.database = ENV['orientdb_database']
```

Anything should work then.